# How to update variable in yaml file with environment variable in azure

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I am creating a pipeline to deploy a application , I have created variable group for database password in azure pipeline and want to use the password values in separate yaml which use to deploy application.
azure-pipeline.yml

```
variables:
- group: databaseCredentials
steps:
- script: |
    set -x
    export POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
```

Below is my secret yaml file , secret.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysecret
type: Opaque
data:
  postgres-password: ${{POSTGRES_PASSWORD}}
```

I want to use the env variable value in yaml file , i tried like this but it fails , i dont want to do search/replace.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to modify your yaml file you may use [Token replace task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens). It will allow you to replace token in file with your variable values.

Here you have example usage:

```yaml
- task: replacetokens@3
  inputs:
    targetFiles: 'yourfile.yaml'
    encoding: 'auto'
    writeBOM: true
    actionOnMissing: 'warn'
    keepToken: false
    tokenPrefix: '#{'
    tokenSuffix: '}#'
    useLegacyPattern: false
    enableTelemetry: true
```

and you file should be:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysecret
type: Opaque
data:
  postgres-password: #{POSTGRES_PASSWORD}#
```

And then you don't need this:

```yaml
steps:
- script: |
    set -x
    export POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
```

Unless there is no other place where you want to use this env variable.

Comment: Thanks @Krzysztof Madej I will try this , how do i approach when I have multiple variables to update ?

Comment: What you need is to put variable name between token prefix and suffix. So next_variable would be `#{NEXT_VARIABLE}#`.